# Converting unicode character to string format

Tags: javascript, unicode

Does anyone know how to convert a unicode to a string in javascript. For instance:

`\u2211 -> ∑`
`\u0032 -> 2`
`\u222B -> ∫`

I basically want to be able to display the symbol in xhtml or html. Haven't decided which I will be using yet.

Comment: `'\u2211' === '∑'`

Comment: I regard this transformation as a security measure, to filter out evil tags from input strings.  
In this case the transformation should be applied repeatedly until there are no more UNICODE escapes left.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just found a way:
`String.fromCharCode(parseInt(unicode,16))` returns the right symbol representation. The unicode here doesn't have the `\u` in front of it just the number.

Answer (score 72):

A function from k.ken's response:

```
function unicodeToChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, 
          function (match) {
               return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
          });
}
```

Takes all unicode characters in the inputted string, and converts them to the character.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between adding `a-f` versus using the case-insensitive global search `/gi` ?

Comment: Not sure. @fuzzyhedge, do you know of any ways to reliably test performance of regular expressions? It certainly would work with the additional a-f

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable it is, but I made a dirty test on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyhedge/ftue79z2/). Explicitly calling the lowercase chars instead of the ignore caps flag is about 1% faster, which seems reasonable. Although the order is probably important.

Answer (score 15):

To convert an given Unicode-Char like  to String-Representation, you can also use this one-liner:

```
var unicodeToStr = ''.codePointAt(0).toString(16)
```

The above example gives you 'F21D'. Used with fontAwesome, you get street-view Icon: '\F21D'

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
const unicodeText = "F1A3";
let unicodeChar = JSON.parse(`["\\u${unicodeText}"]`)[0];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in my react native project! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: It won't work for if the normal string has Unicode. ex: "doesn&#039;t works"

Comment: **Brilliant!** This works for a longer string that has some Unicode char embedded in it. Example: `'Tom \u0026 Jerry' -> 'Tom & Jerry'`. Although Bryan's answer may also do that, it requires defining a function whereas your answer is an elegant one-liner. Note though: ``const string = "Tom \u0026 Jerry"; console.log( JSON.parse(`["${string}"]`)[0] ); // output: Tom & Jerry``

Comment: This fails for surrogate pairs like emojis.

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = '/0004';  // One of unicode
var unicodeToStr = string.codePointAt(0).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This outputs Grinning Face `U+1F600`:
// https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1f600
const code = "".trim().codePointAt(0).toString(16);
console.log(code); // 1f600

// Convert it back to string
const str = "\u{1f600}";
const str2 = String.fromCodePoint(0x1f600);

console.log( str, str2, ''.normalize() === str.normalize());
```

**References:**

- [MDN String.codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)
- [MDN Normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)