# Populating properties at runtime

Tags: javascript

I have an view object (esri, javascript 4.9) and i am trying to populate the properties.

The code block works fine when i hard code in the values, but it is failing when i try to use a string variable at runtime.

Here is the code, populated with hard coded values

```
    view.graphics.add({
      id: "centers",
      symbol: {
        type: "text",
        color: "black",
        text: "\ue62f",
        font: {
          size: this._defCallLocSize,
          family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
        }
      },
      geometry: {
        type: "point",
        latitude: parseFloat(_lat),
        longitude: parseFloat(_lon)
      },
      popupTemplate: {
        title: "",
        content: ""
      }
    });
```

And here is the code with the global variable

```
    view.graphics.add({
      id: "centers",
      symbol: {
        type: "text",
        color: this._defCallLocColor,
        text: this._defCallLocIcon,
        font: {
          size: this._defCallLocSize,
          family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
        }
      },
      geometry: {
        type: "point",
        latitude: parseFloat(_lat),
        longitude: parseFloat(_lon)
      },
      popupTemplate: {
        title: "",
        content: ""
      }
    });
```

The this._defCallLocColor, when looked at in the debugger, acts like a string (  "black"  )
but during runtime, the color is being displayed as white (default esri)

Now to add a little more to the mix...   the lat and lon are working correctly, using global _lat and _lon

So the primary question is this,  why is the global variable this._defCallLocColor  not being seen as a string when being placed into the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is....   it is a unicode issue, javascript does not represent unicode into a string as i was expecting it.  So i found a quick fiddle
from 
user4322543 
on this thread...
[Converting unicode character to string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267329/converting-unicode-character-to-string-format)

While adding the inline code to correct the unicode into a regular string..

```
        color: this._defCallLocColor,
        text: unicodeToCharIgnoreCap(this._defCallLocIcon),
        font: {
          size: this._defCallLocSize,
```

Provided a solution that works.