# How to replace unicode characters using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, alphanumeric

I need to use Regex to replace any character other than alphanumeric or `.` with an underscore using Javascript.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "at (1).mp4";
  var result = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+/g, "_");
}
```

This works great but I have an edge case:

If the string is `54NV-\u4e3b\u56fe\u89c6\u9891.mp4`, this function converts it to `54NV_.mp4`. Is there a way to replace `\` and preserve the `u4e3b` etc.?

Any ideas?

Comment: What does that input string look like? If it's not a raw string, that `\u4e3b` will be turned into a unicode character

Comment: The input string does not actually contain the characters `\u4e3b` though, those are converted to their equivalent unicode character before your code is reached. The only way I see to do this is to check each character of your string and replace unicode characters with their unicode escape sequences, you could use the string `charCodeAt` method to calculate the right escape sequence for each character.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641297/3832970. You might use something like `s.replace(/[^ -~]/g, x => "_" + x.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+/g, "_")`. The `/[^ -~]/g` might be replaced with `/[^\x00-~]/g`

Comment: if string is `\u4e3b` how many characters, yes ?