# JSON file doesn't show Arabic/Persian characters correctly

Tags: json, unicode, utf-8

I have a JSON file :

```
{
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_index": "newsvit",
  "_source": {
    "content": "  \u0628\u0647 \u06af\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0634 \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u0627\u060c \u062a\u06cc\u0645 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u062a\u0628\u0631\u06cc\u0632 \u0648 \u0646\u0641\u062a \u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0632 ",
    "agency": "36",
    "date_created": 1494521741,
    "url": "http://www.irna.ir/fa/News/82525960/",
    "image": "uploads/2017/05/11/2561366787.jpg",
    "category": "5"
  },
  "_type": "news",
  "_id": "2981938"
}
```

and it shows Persian/Arabic characters like in the content section while it should show correctly. what is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem.  Escaping of unicode characters is explicitly permitted by [RFC7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7)

Comment: You didn’t mention the programming language, but languages like Python have JSON libraries that parse and return a language-appropriate structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is working as intended. It is called Unicode and is a standard way of encoding characters, often used in programming to represent characters outside of standard ASCII character sets.

JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html - "string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes."

Unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: yes, but is there a way to actually see what it is? I want to import this data into elasticsearch

Comment: Yep, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267329/converting-unicode-character-to-string-format

Comment: Also once you parse the JSON in NodeJS it will be a regular string in memory. It only uses the unicode strings as an intermediate format whilst encoding to JSON. Does that make sense?